# Do I need to configure azureAD for powerapps?

Tags: azure, active-directory, powerapps

I am new to powerapps, and I need to create an app with AzureAD authentication. But I am confused by this authentication. Do I understand correctly that I don't have to implement user sign-up and login screens, because every user which will be added to AzureAD would be able to login to microsoft account and will have an access to my powerapp?

So, I don't have to write any code for user signup/login/forgot password? 
But in the Internet I saw that some people use `AzureAD.getUser()` and `Office365.User`. When do I need it?

Comment: Any followup questions?

Answer (score 1):

PowerApps is building enterprise apps for your organization staffs. This app has to be developed, published and shared to AD users, and users can sign-in using Active directory single sign-on.

You can invite/share with AD individuals, security group or O365 group. But not Distribution groups. You can share the app to all users by sharing with “Everyone”.

Even PowerApps can be shared with external users (guests) but they must be guest users of an Azure Active Directory tenant.

[How to share a PowerApp?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/share-app)

Yes, no signup or login other than Microsoft AD login/challenge screen.

Those snippets will be used to get current logged in user details.

Answer (score 0):

Everything @ArunVinoth said and to add a little more info about:
`But in the Internet I saw that some people use AzureAD.getUser() and Office365.User. When do I need it?`:

- These are PowerApps connectors (API wrappers) that allow you to surface AD/O365 data *within the app* for your users.
- Example:

  - You may have a way for users to lookup contact information for people within the org.
  - You would add the Office365Users connector to your application
  - Then execute the `.SearchUser` method from that connector to display contact info based on user input.

These connectors are not for authenticating to the app, but rather providing lookup capabilities for your users. Or automating these lookups for your app logic.